# Machine learning on or of some data?

Tags: grammar, terminology, programming

If it's machine learning using some platform or technology, it makes sense to use "on" ("ML on AWS"), but if we are talking about applying ML to some data, should "on" or "of" be used? Below two examples of real world usage:

- ...machine learning of collective variables...
- ...machine learning on binary data...

My specific question is about the phrase "Using machine learning of demographics and personal history to predict XYZ." Should that be "Using machine learning on demographics and personal history to predict XYZ" instead?

There might be a better Stack Exchange site to post this on, but I wasn't sure. Feel free to move or let me know if this is the case.

Comment: I'd suggest ComputerScience.SE.

Comment: Either one works. 'on' emphasizes that there is a process (machine learning) that acts on a thing, the things to be learned.  'of' is less emphatic and makes it the descriptor of machine learning. X of Y -> Y-style X, so 'Personal history machine learning'

Comment: Why does it have to be *using*?  Why not use your sentence in the question?  *Applying machine learning to demographic and personal history data to predict XYZ*.    Or you could consider *Using machine learning **with** demographic ...”